# How to assign the output of calculation to a shell variable

Tags: shell

I wanted to do this calculation a * 256 ** 3 + b * 256 ** 2 + c * 256 + d and assign output to variable and print dec.

```
dec ='a * 256 ** 3 + b * 256 ** 2 + c * 256 + d'
echo $dec
```

I am getting syntax error with the above lines.

Comment: ["Shellscript" is not a language](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292023/let-shellscript-burn-in-shell). What shell are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, assignment is done this way

```
dec='a * 256 ** 3 + b * 256 ** 2 + c * 256 + d'
```

This is where your syntax error come from.
Then you just have to evaluate your string with the operator $(( )) this way :

```
echo $((dec))
```

Comment: flag=$($dec&(1<<31)) : to see if 31st bit is on,I am using this flag. But syntax error. I could not solve

Comment: @user3823859 it's a completely separate question but I think you're looking for `flag=$(( dec & 1<<31 ))`. The double parentheses are needed for an arithmetic context.

Comment: dec2ip () {
    local ip dec=$@
    if [ $dec < 0 ]
    then
       dec = $(( dec + 429496796 ))
    for e in {3..0}
    do
        ((octet = dec / (256 ** e) ))
        ((dec -= octet * 256 ** e))
        ip+=$delim$octet
        delim=.
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$ip"
}
I solved half of the problem with this, but it shows error:  syntax error near unexpected token `}'

Answer (score 1):

For **integer** arithmetic, you can use the shell:

```
dec=$(( a * 256 ** 3 + b * 256 ** 2 + c * 256 + d ))
echo "$dec"
```

This uses an arithmetic context `(( ... ))` to calculate the value.

Note that there is no space in an assignment, this is important!

The shell does not support floating point arithmetic, but `bc` or `awk` do. For example, using awk (and assuming that you have shell variables `$a`, `$b`, `$c` and `$d` defined):

```
awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" -v c="$c" -v d="$d" 'BEGIN{print a * 256 ** 3 + b * 256 ** 2 + c * 256 + d}'
```

or using bc:

```
printf '%s * 256 ^ 3 + %s * 256 ^ 2 + %s * 256 + %s\n' "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d" | bc -l
```

Using the string format specifier `%s` for each of the shell variables means that no precision is lost before passing the values to bc.