# Twos complement of decimal number

Tags: shell, decimal, twos-complement

I wanted to find twos complement of a decimal number using the shell.
can anyone please help me?

Comment: Have you tried to solve this problem yourself? If so, what problems did you encounter? Please [edit] your question to show us. This seems to be related to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30049179/2088135)

Answer (score 1):

Two's complement works in binary, so given the number of bit of your number, you can deal with decimal numbers like:

```
if number >= pow(2, N - 1)
    return number
else
    return number - pow(2, N)
```

**Example:**

```
N = 3
number = 2
number is less than pow(2, 3 - 1) = 4, so result = number = 2

N = 3
number = 6
number is greater than pow(2, 3 - 1) = 4, so result = number - pow(2, 4) = 6 - 8 = -2
```

I took the idea from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

**BASH**

```
#!/bin/bash

NUMBER="$1"
BITS="$2"

# I check the presence of the arguments
if [ -z "$NUMBER" -o -z "$BITS" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <number> <n_bits>"
    exit
fi

# I check the arguments are numeric values
RE='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $NUMBER =~ $RE ]] || ! [[ $BITS =~ $RE ]] ; then
    echo "The inputs must be numeric values"
    exit
fi

# Calculate, with awk, the powers I need
N_POW=$(awk "BEGIN{ print 2 ** $BITS }")
NM1_POW=$(awk "BEGIN{ print 2 ** ($BITS - 1) }")

# Result...
if [ $NUMBER -lt $NM1_POW ];
then
    echo $NUMBER
else
    echo $(($NUMBER - $N_POW))
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the _using the shell_ part of the problem.

Comment: paste this in a my_script.sh file and run sh my_script.sh in the shell

Answer (score 1):

You can try with bc:

```
dec=-4; bits=6;
bin=$(printf "%0.${bits}d\n" $(echo "ibase=10;obase=2;$(((2**(bits))+$dec))" | bc) )
bin=$(echo $bin | grep -oE "[[:digit:]]{$bits}$")
echo $bin
111100
```